# Batch file console not stopping to display the output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to execute a **batch file** but its console is not stopping for its output.

*here's the code:*

```
goto D:
cd postgresql-9.6.0-1-windows-x64-binaries
cd pgsql
cd bin
start pg_ctl start -D D:\pg_data\data
@echo on
echo server started
pause
```

Comment: In general it is always advisable to specify an application or script (batch file) to start with file extension and with full path. I don't know of which type `pg_ctl` really is because of missing file extension. I suggest to replace everything above `@echo on` by `start "" /D"D:\postgresql-9.6.0-1-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin" "pg_ctl.exe" start -D "D:\pg_data\data"` or by `start "" "D:\postgresql-9.6.0-1-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin\pg_ctl.exe" start -D "D:\pg_data\data"` with assuming the file extension for `pg_ctl` is `.exe`. Run in a command prompt window `start /?` for its help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming it is on the D: drive. use `cd /d` see `cd /?` for the reason why.

```
@echo off   
cd /d "D:\postgresql-9.6.0-1-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin"
start "" "pg_ctl" start -D "D:\pg_data\data"
echo server started
pause
```

change to `start "" /wait` if you want to wait for the service to start before you echo it has been started.

Comment: The option `/wait` does not result in halting batch file execution until `pg_ctl` is started, it halts batch file execution until `pg_ctl` has terminated itself. I don't know what `pg_ctl` really does. It perhaps is just a launcher like `start` and quickly terminates itself. In this case your description in last sentence is right. Otherwise the usage of `/wait` would not make much sense if `pg_ctl` runs for example as long as Windows is running once started.

Comment: @Mofi Yes, that is what I mean. It is of no use to echo `service started` if the startup process is still running, so we halt the batch file. That being said, it is still bad to assume the service has started, what if it failed, we still echo `service started` :)